# Does an SSD use less power than a platter/regular drive?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, power-supply, battery

The answer to this question seems obvious to me but I'm asking it in case I've missed something.

I have a laptop with a small SSD drive and a large regular/platter drive. I keep a collection of videos on the large drive. If I'm on battery power then my strategy is to copy the video that I'm watching to the SSD and watch it from there to save battery power instead of streaming it from the platter drive.

Am I really saving power and extending the view time while running on battery? If so, is this power saving significant or is it negligible such that I'm wasting my time doing it?

Comment: Depends on the drive

Comment: You would be saving power if the HD spins-down, and stays down. You would not be saving that much power if the HD was not going into standby and spinning down. The savings would be signnificant if the screen backlight was low and the effort made by the cpu and gpu are low. (different render methods and player programs and codecs for videos can use more or less power).   And yes one drive or drive set can spin-down and stay down on desktop or laptop, while another drive or drive set is awakened and being used. Some of that dependant on not just you but the system itself doing things with it.